# How can I create polymer custom element with shadow dom so that I can access it's shadowRoot?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom, polymer-cli

I have use Polymer-cli (version 0.16.0) to scaffold a polymer project but could not access shadow-root using the console:

`var element = document.getElementsByTagName("my-app")[0].shadowRoot` returns undefined so It looks like shadow DOM is on closed mode.

How can I force a custom-element to use open mode so I can access it's shadowRoot from outside ?

Edited 2:
The main question here is what needs to be done to access the shadowRoot so I changed the question a little bit to not be related with shadow DOM mode

Edited:

Reference to close modes on https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#advanced Advanced topics section

Steps to reproduce scenario:

```
npm install -g polymer-cli
mkdir my-app
cd my-app
polymer init starter-kit
polymer serve --open
```

Some code snippets:

index.html:

```
...
<head>
...
    <script>
      // Setup Polymer options
      window.Polymer = {
        dom: 'shadow',
        lazyRegister: true
      };

      // Load webcomponentsjs polyfill if browser does not support native Web Components
      (function() {
        'use strict';

        var onload = function() {
          // For native Imports, manually fire WebComponentsReady so user code
          // can use the same code path for native and polyfill'd imports.
          if (!window.HTMLImports) {
            document.dispatchEvent(
              new CustomEvent('WebComponentsReady', {bubbles: true})
            );
          }
        };

        var webComponentsSupported = (
          'registerElement' in document
          && 'import' in document.createElement('link')
          && 'content' in document.createElement('template')
        );

        if (!webComponentsSupported) {
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.async = true;
          script.src = '/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js';
          script.onload = onload;
          document.head.appendChild(script);
        } else {
          onload();
        }
      })();

      // Load pre-caching Service Worker
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
        });
      }
    </script>

    <link rel="import" href="/src/my-app.html">
...
</head>
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

my-app.html:

```
...
<dom-module id="my-app">

<template>
...
</template>

  <script>

    Polymer({

      is: 'my-app',

      properties: {

        page: {
          type: String,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          observer: '_pageChanged'
        }

      },

      observers: [
      '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)'
      ],

      _routePageChanged: function(page) {
        this.page = page || 'view1';
      },

      _pageChanged: function(page) {
        // Load page import on demand. Show 404 page if fails
        var resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl('my-' + page + '.html');
        this.importHref(resolvedPageUrl, null, this._showPage404, true);
      },

      _showPage404: function() {
        this.page = 'view404';
      }

    });

  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Comment: Can you add some code

Comment: What is open and closed mode?

Comment: Note also that if you want to polyfill Shadow DOM on Firefox you should download webcomponents.js instead of webcomponents-lite.js that doesn't include the Shadow DOM polyfill.

Comment: What's written in the console?

Answer (score 0):

If you use shady DOM (default) then there is no `shadowRoot`.

See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings how to enable shadow DOM.

Something like this should work

```
var element = Polymer.dom(document.getElementsByTagName("my-app")[0]).root
```

For more details see https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom

Comment: Edited to include dom settings: it's defined as "shadow". `var element = Polymer.dom(document.getElementsByTagName("my-app")[0]).root` also returns undefined from console

Comment: When you enable shadow DOM, you don't need `Polymer.dom(...)`. What does `document.getElementsByTagName("my-app")[0]` return?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("my-app")[0]` returns `<my-app page="view1">#shadow-root (open)</my-app>` with .root or .shadowRoot or with Polymer.dom it returns undefined

Comment: Google Chrome linux Version 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit)
Mozilla Firefox linux 49.0.1

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I'm using Polymer only with Dart and don't know details about using it with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should work. See the snippet below.

Maybe you don't add the `{ dom: 'shadow' }` setting at the right place. It should be defined before `<link>` to `polymer.html`.

```js
output.textContent = document.querySelector('my-app').shadowRoot
```

```html
<head>
  <script>
    window.Polymer = {
      dom: 'shadow',
      lazyRegister: true
    }
  </script>
  <link rel=import href="https://rawgit.com/polymer/polymer/master/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="my-app">
    <template>
      Hello
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-app'
      })
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <my-app></my-app>
  <div id=output></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I didn't edited the code, it is scaffolded in the *steps to reproduce scenario* section in the question. And the test is run on browser console, I also think it _should_ run but don't

Comment: Then you should open an issue on the site of the editor if you think the issue is not your fault